# entity framework core migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm new to Ef core. Using migrations. I made some changes in my code recently. 
Got following error:

The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_JobPosts_Role_Domain1_Filters_Item1_ExperienceLevelId' already exists on table 'JobPosts'.

Ok, so I did what I usually do  when I encounter errors, delete my database and previous migrations and start all over again.

First migration works fine everytime. Second migration prompts the same error even though no changes has been made to my code.

Why does it keep adding columns that already exists?

Comment: can you provide the migration files generated by ef?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that ef core does not support nested owned types.